# How many convolutions are necessary for all possible $K-1$-fold convolutions of $K$ vectors?

Tags: combinatorics, convolution

> There are $K$ vectors and all possible $K-1$-fold convolutions are needed to be determined. How many minimum number of convolutions are necessary?

**Here is an example:**

Lets assume we have $K=4$. Then we have four vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, $v_4$ and the followings are to be computed:

$1.$ $v_1\star v_2\star v_3$  here we need $2$ convolutions

$2.$ $v_1\star v_2\star v_4$  here we need $1$ convolution because we already have $v_1\star v_2$ from the previous step

$3.$ $v_3\star v_4\star v_1$  here we need $2$ convolutions

$4.$ $v_3\star v_4\star v_2$  here we need $1$ convolution because we already have $v_3\star v_4$ from the previous step.

> Altogether one needs $6$ convolutions which is normally $8$, if we do not use the convolutions already done in the previous steps.

If we use the same idea for $K=5$

$1.$ $v_1\star v_2\star v_3\star v_4$  here we need $3$ convolutions

$2.$ $v_1\star v_2\star v_3\star v_5$  here we need $1$ convolution

$3.$ $v_1\star v_2\star v_4\star v_5$  here we need $2$ convolutions

$4.$ $v_5\star v_4\star v_3\star v_1$  here we need $3$ convolutions

$5.$ $v_5\star v_4\star v_3\star v_2$  here we need $1$ convolutions

> Altogether one needs $10$ convolutions which is normally $15$, if we do not use the convolutions already done in the previous steps.

For $K=6$ one can reduce $24$ convolutions to $14$ and for $K=7$ instead of $35$ convolutions one only needs to calcule $19$ (added: it is actually $18$ according to my new calculation) convolutions if I am not mistaken.

**Here are the questions:**

> **Question** $1$**:** I am wondering for a possible generalization to this. For example if we have $K=1000$ or $K=1000000$? How many minimum number of convolutions are necessary?

I can also find all $K-1$ convolutions by first convolving all $K$ vectors with each other resulting in say vector $v$. Then I go ahead with deconvolving $v$ with $v_1$, then deconvolving $v$ with $v_2$, etc.

In this way, I need to make only $999$ convolutions and $1000$ deconvolutions. 
However the size of devonvolutions is much bigger than the size of convolutions. For example if the length of $v_1$ is $10$, then all convolutions are between vectors of size $1\times 10$. However, if we use the deconvolution idea, the deconvoltion will be beween a vector of size $10$ and size $9001$ for $K=1000$. Moreover, deconvolution is not always reliable.

> **Question** $2$**:** which idea is the best to obtain $K-1$-fold convoltions with less number of computations for example if one wants to implement using a computer program?

Here is the figure that I got from my examples above. The y axis is the ratio of the minimum that I found by my hands to the clairvoyent so $K(K-2)$. It is almost linear but it wont be like that forever..

[image]

Here is my handwork for $K=8$:[image]

> So accroding to my examples, the answer should be $4K-10$, which is surprisingly linear. If true, it is also very interesting because for large $K$, one needs to have a very good strategy to achieve the minimum number of convolutions.. what should be the strategy? how can one prove it, if correct?

Comment: Convolution is the same as product. You want to find how many multiplications are needed to compute $f(K-1,K)$ the set of all products of $K-1$ distinct elements from a given set with $K$ elements. What I can say is that we need $2^K-K-1$ multiplications to compute $F(K)=\bigcup_{n=0}^K f(n,K)$ : proof every time we do a multiplication we have computed at most one new element in $F(K)$ and there are $2^K$ elements in $F(K)$ and $K+1$ of them are given. The obvious algorithm (putting an order and computing the least elements first) needs $2^K-K-1$ multiplications to compute $F(K)$.

Comment: @reuns Sorry but no. For $K=1000$, a clairvoyent way of handling this problem requires 1 million convolutions. Simply 999 convolutions for each case. Since there are 1000 cases, we have almost 1 millon convolutions. According to what you wrote we need about $2^{1000}$. It is impossible. I think 1 million is still too many. Because a clever way will probably need some $10000$s according to my best guess. And the question: what is this clever way and how many?

Comment: @reuns Okey, and what does it then say for $K=1000$? could you please also make comments on the given examples in the question? The complexity is definitely not exponential.

Comment: $f(n,K)$ contains ${K \choose n}$ elements while $F(K)$ contains $2^K$ elements. Why would you want to look specifically at $f(K-1,K)$ ? How do you prove that the complexity is polynomial in $K$ ?

Comment: @reuns Because it is simply polynomial as I said. For K vectors, there are (K,K-1) combinations, which is K. For each case, at worst we must make K-2 convolutions. Then the complexity as at most K(K-2). Example K=4. we have v1,v2,v3,v4. Then (K,K-1) =4, so there are 4 cases in total. These cases are v1v2v3, v1v2v4,v1v3v4,v2v3v4, because convolving a with b or b with a are the same. So for each case, we need to do 2 convolutions for example for v1v2v3, v1 convolved with v2, then the result is convolved with v3. So in total we have 4*(4-2)=8 convolutions. So K(K-2) is the worst case complexity.

Comment: What is convolution here? Is it commutative? I don't understand the pattern in the order of convolutions given in your examples. Could you not just compute $a_1 = v_1$, $a_2 = a_1 \star v_2, \dots, a_{K-1} = a_{K-2} \star v_{K-1}$, and $b_1 = v_K$, $b_2 = v_{K-1} \star b_1, \dots, b_{K-1} = v_2 \star b_{K-2}$, so the desired convolutions are $a_{K-1}, a_{K-2} \star b_1, \dots, a_1 \star b_{K-2}, b_{K-1}$ with a total of $3(K-2)$ convolutions?

Comment: @user125932 seems it is working great. I didnt get this part $b_{K-1}=v_2\star b_{k-2}$. Wouldnt $v_2$ be something like $v_{K-k+2}$ or something like that? It seems to me that in the equations regarding $b$, index of $v$ should be decreasing right? For $K=5$ I have the following: $b_1=v_5$, $b_2=v_4\star b_1$, $b_3=v_3\star b_2$ and $b_4=v_2\star b_3$ am I right?

Comment: right -- I'll add an answer to clarify my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand a bit on my comment, here's an approach that uses only $3K-6$ convolutions -- I'm not sure that it's optimal, but it's near optimal in the sense that at least $\approx 2K$ convolutions are necessary.

First compute the $2K-2$ vectors
\begin{align*}
a_1 &= v_1  
& b_1 &= v_K\\
a_2 &= a_1 \star v_2 = v_1 \star v_2 
& b_2 &= v_{K-1} \star b_1 = v_{K-1} \star v_K\\
a_3 &= a_2 \star v_3 = v_1 \star v_2 \star v_3
& b_3 &= v_{K-2} \star b_2 = v_{K-2} \star v_{K-1} \star v_K\\
&\vdots 
&&\vdots\\ 
a_{K-1} &= a_{K-2} \star v_{K-1} = v_1 \star v_2 \star \cdots \star v_{K-1}
& b_{K-1} &= v_2 \star b_{K-2} = v_2 \star v_3 \star \cdots \star v_k
\end{align*}
(so generally for $2 \leq i \leq K-1$, $a_i := a_{i-1} \star v_i$ and $b_i := v_{K+1-i} \star b_{i-1}$), using $2(K-2)$ convolutions.

The desired $(K-1)$-fold convolutions are $a_{K-1}, a_{K-2} \star b_1, a_{K-3} \star b_2, \dots, a_1 \star b_{K-2}, b_{K-1}$. Each of these $K$ except for the first and last uses an additional convolution, giving a total of $3K-6$ convolutions.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a faster way. Instead of taking $K^2$ convolutions, it can be done in $O(K\log K)$ convolutions. I will refer to $v_1\star \dots \star v_{i-1}\star v_{i+1}\star\dots v_K$ as a "deficient convolution" of $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_K\}$. You want to compute all deficient convolutions.

The base cases of the algorithm are when $K=1,2,3$. In the firs two cases, zero convolutions are needed, and for $K=3$, three convolutions are required. From now on, assume $K\ge 4$.

Split $v_1,\dots,v_K$ into two sets $A$ and $B$ with $\lfloor K/2\rfloor$ and $\lceil K/2\rceil$ vectors. Recursively compute all of the deficient convolutions of $A$ and $B$. Furthermore, compute the convolution of all elements in $A$, call it $v_A$, and similarly compute $v_B$. Finally, compute the convolution of $v_A$ with all the deficient convolutions for $B$, then the convolution of $v_B$ with all deficient convolutions for $A$. Combined, these make all deficient convolutions for $A\cup B=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_K\}$.

Assuming for the moment that $K=2^k$ is a power of two, the number of convolutions required can be computed exactly as
\begin{align}
(2^k+2)+2(2^{k-1}+2)+4(2^{k-2}+2)+\dots+2^{k-2}(2^2+2)
&=(k-1)2^k+2\cdot (2^{k-1}-1)\\
&\le K\log_2 K+2K\\
&\in O(K\log K)
\end{align}
Furthermore, since it can be easy shown by induction that the number of convolutions required grows monotonically in $K$. Therefore, the bound for powers of two extends to all values of $K$ (perhaps with an additional constant factor of two).

Comment: I think I found the answer although I have no proof for that. The answer is $4K-10$. You can see that this result is true for all given examples. Plus I did also for $8$ by hands and it is indeed $22$! It is really surprising that for $K=10^6$ one needs only around $4$ million convolutions..

Comment: I edited the question with some more material..

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Be careful with extrapolating trends which are only supported by a couple small numbers. I see no reason to believe $4K-10$ is achievable in general.

Comment: It is just true for $K=4,5,6,7,8$ and I can try it for $9$. if I find $26$, will you believe that it is possible? your result is fairly off for all examples. For example for $K=8$ your exact result it $38$ but the best result is $22$. This alone says that there should be somethin better.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I had small mistake in computation of the exact number of steps, stemming from a wrong base case. My method indeed achieves $22$ convolutions when $K=8$, and furthermore agrees with your results for $K=3,4,5,6,7$. However, when $K=9$ I get $27$ convolutions instead of $26$. Let us see if you can do better.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören Well, I feel silly now; as [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3386741/how-many-convolutions-are-necessary-for-all-possible-k-1-fold-convolutions-of#comment6968599_3386741) explains, there is a solution linear in $K$, specifically $3K-6$. With $K=5$, you only need $9$ convolutions, for example.

Comment: I was able to justify that it works for $ K=5$ and $9$ is true. I believe that it is indeed working for all $K$ and $3K-6$ is just crazy.